# Keeping try/catch blocks in the release version of an app

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a mobile application that will be put on the app store and utilized by consumers, a process I have never gone through before. I'm wondering if i should utilize try/catch blocks for the part of the application that deals with uploading files. I'm wanting to utilize this in the case that the file doesn't upload - instead of crashing the app, using try/catch blocks will allow the user to be notified their file hasn't been uploaded.

Is this good practice? It seems like it would be smart to alert the user of this opposed to just shutting the app down when it happens. I'm not sure if try/catch is the best way to go about that or if any of you would recommend a better strategy.

I was thinking i'd do something like this:

```
try
{
   UploadFile(byte[] file)
}

catch
{
  await DisplayAlert("The file has failed to upload.");
}
```

Any recommendations would be appreciated

Comment: Seems like a good idea. Also could add line to a log for yourself, so you could handle the reason for the failure in the future. There are several online services that can handle pulling logs from users of your application.

Comment: try/catch is very necessary, but the way you use it here (just catch) is wrong 99% of the time.   You should only catch exceptions you can handle (e.g. trying to delete a file that is not there).   In your example, you also catch (and ignore) out of memory errors (and tell the user the wrong error message), which is never a good thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a good approach. User application should not crash anyway, and `try/catch` is a good practice to avoid it.

Of course, you can combine usual checks using `if/then` and `try/catch` blocks. For example, if no internet connection present, user cannot upload files obviously. So you can write

```
try
{
   if (InternetConnectionPresent())
       UploadFile(byte[] file);
   else
       await DisplayAlert("Please check your internet connection.");
}

catch
{
  await DisplayAlert("The file has failed to upload.");
}
```

Also, `try/catch` blocks gives you an additional possibility to analyze unexpected behavior of your application. You can use, for example, [Analytics center from Microsoft](https://appcenter.ms/), so your `catch` section will looks like:

```
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes; // you need to add this package to your project
.....
catch (Exception e)
{
  var dictionaryCrash = new Dictionary<string, string>
  {
       {  "additional information", _any_info_you_want_to_know_ }
  };
  Crashes.TrackError(e, dictionaryCrash);
  await DisplayAlert("The file has failed to upload.");
}
```

***Update:***

As mentioned in the comments, it should be better to handle different exception in different sections, e.g.:

```
try
{
...
} 
catch (NetworkException e)
{
  // something wrong with connection
}
catch (AutenticationException e)
{
  // bad login
}
catch (IOException e)
{
  // something wrong with disk
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  // all others exceptions
}
```

You should not try to proceed all possible exceptions (there are hundreds of them!), but you can predict which exceptions could be thrown more probably and handle them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations! I've never really gone about handling exceptions. My app simply calls the functions under obvious conditions and performs those functions the user requests them. So I have another question: how far should i go with exception handling? do i make a try/catch statement for every single exception I can possible think of? ie: if theres no internet, if the login to the server failed, if the storage is full, etc. How far do i go with exception handling?

Comment: Or should i just do one singular try/catch block for each area of the program i could see there being a failure - and not make the try/catch block SPECIFIC to the potential error that could occur (in other words, i shouldn't make a try/catch block for bad internet connection and another for the case where my storage is full) ?

Comment: @Neil any suggestions to my above comments?

Comment: thank you for the feedback, I'll try doing that in my application!